# Compare current month rate against a base rate (old rate) using .shift() option

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have large dataset of projects with employee specific monthly billing rate along with billing hours. I am looking to create python code which can detect rate change for an employee and derive incremental increase (New-old) by comparing with old rate (base rate) every month. I have tried using following code:

Simplified version of my dataset (df) looks like below:

```
   Proj_ID Empl_ID    Bill_Date Bill_Rate Bill_hours
    1234   780313     1/31/2020    20        174.5
    1234   780313     2/29/2020    25        160
    1234   780313     3/31/2020    25        130
    1234   780313     4/30/2020    25        145
    7890   832123     1/31/2020    10        160
    7890   832123     2/29/2020    15        125
    7890   832123     3/31/2020    15        138
    7890   832123     4/30/2020    15        156
```

Assigned key with a combination of Project and employee Id as unique
identifier:

```
df['key'] = df['Project_ID'] + df['Employee_ID']
```

Created below code using `np.where` & `.shift` to detect rate increase
by comparing current rate against previous rate of the 'key' to
detect increase(Y/N) and derive incremental revenue for the month:

```
df['Inc_Y/N'] = np.where((df['Bill_Rate'] - df.groupby(['key']).Bill_Rate.shift(1))>0, 'Yes', 'No')
            
df['Inc_rev'] = (df['Bill_Rate'] - df.groupby(['key']).Bill_Rate.shift(1))*df['Bill_hours']
```

Based on the above, the code was able to detect rate increase in Feb
(for project 1234) and March (For project 7890) and incremental
increase for the month as below:

```
Proj_ID Emp_ID Bill_Date Bill_Rate Bill_hours Inc_Y/N Inc_rev
 1234   780313 1/31/2020    20       174.5    No      0
 1234   780313 2/29/2020    25        160     Yes     800
 1234   780313 3/31/2020    25        130     No      0
 1234   780313 4/30/2020    25        145     No      0
 7890   832123 1/31/2020    10        160     No      0
 7890   832123 2/29/2020    10        125     No      0
 7890   832123 3/31/2020    15        138     Yes     690
 7890   832123 4/30/2020    15        156     No      0
```

However, in the above output, for months succeeding the rate increase, Eg: Project 1234 - the code is comparing Mar 31 rate (25) against the preceding rate of Feb 29 (25) instead of old rate of Jan 31 (20) due to which I am getting the incremental revenue for those months as 0.

Can anyone please advise on where im going wrong?

Comment: You will have to post what you have tried so far by coding. Otherwise, people are reluctant to code things for you here on SO

Comment: Hi, i have included the code i tried in the above question. But would need help on the query to get the correct output.

Comment: To make sure I understand - if the rate is 6, 10, 10 over three months, the expected increase is 0, 4, 4 (as opposed to 0, 4, 0 which is what you're seeing now)?

Comment: Yes @Roy2012.. you are right .. I would need 0,4,4 as expected increase

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do:

```
df["first_month_rate"] = df.groupby("Proj_ID").Bill_Rate.transform("first")
df["Inc_rev"] = (df.Bill_Rate - df.first_month_rate) * df.Bill_hours

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Proj_ID  Empl_ID  Bill_Date  Bill_Rate  Bill_hours  first_month_rate  Inc_rev
0     1234   780313 2020-01-31         20       174.5                20      0.0
1     1234   780313 2020-02-29         25       160.0                20    800.0
2     1234   780313 2020-03-31         25       130.0                20    650.0
3     1234   780313 2020-04-30         25       145.0                20    725.0
4     7890   832123 2020-01-31         10       160.0                10      0.0
5     7890   832123 2020-02-29         15       125.0                10    625.0
6     7890   832123 2020-03-31         15       138.0                10    690.0
7     7890   832123 2020-04-30         15       156.0                10    780.0
```

Comment: Thanks @Roy2012. However for the second dataset (Proj-7840), what if the rate increase (15) happens in March instead or say April?.. the code should be able to assign the month preceding the increased month as the first month. How do i include that in the code?

Comment: Not sure I understand. Could you please add the relevant example - as well as the expected output - to the question?

Comment: If I understand correctly, if the rates are 10-10-10-15, the increase should be 0-0-0-5. Shouldn't they?

Comment: Yes @Roy2012... your solution worked on my larger database. Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Great. Could you please accept my answer for future generations?